# GPUImage Large PNG Files

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I can capture a still image on an iPad Retina Display with GPUImage using the crop filter (to 8x10 ratio with a size of 2420x1936 pixels = 4.68 megabytes) using capturePhotoAsPNGProcessedUpToFilter. The resulting PNG is 10mb, almost double the size of what an uncompressed image would be.

Is there a setting I am missing for PNG processing? Is there another way to reduce the size of the PNG file during capture?

A file this large really slows down things downstream.

Thanks for any advice or help!

Comment: An uncompressed image at 2420x1936, with four bytes per pixel (RGBA) is 18.7 MB, not 4.68. Does it have to be a PNG, or can you use JPEG output?

Comment: So, I can't do byte math ;) Actually, I was using GPUImageChromaKeyBlend with a transparent background image to generate a PNG with transparency where the green was, so I need a PNG. BTW, GPUImageChromaKey did not show the transparency in real-time camera feed (although it did save it with transparency, just couldn't adjust the intensity and get feedback like I could with the blend tool).

Comment: Remember that GPUImageView doesn't currently support transparency, so if you were trying to overlay the result of a GPUImageChromaKeyFilter (not the blend) on another view, it wouldn't show the contents behind the view. Enough people are confused by this that I might need to add a toggle for this capability.